# JavaScript - Tidy way of ensuring multiple strings don't equal each other

Tags: javascript

I would have thought this question exists but can't seem to find an answer.

I have 4 variables and I want to ensure the contents (string) of each are unique/not equal to any other.

So i know I could do this with a long `if` statement and multiple checks e.g.

```
var a = 'aword';
var b = 'bword';
var c = 'cword';
var d = 'dword';

if (a != b && a !=c && a !=d && b!=c........) { ... }
```

However this is quite long winded, is there a simpler way that I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: do you care about case sensitivity? is this the only spot where you need this check, and you only have 4 vars, i think the way it is is fine. But you have more places that you need to perform this check, then you need a function to do this.

Comment: Is it always going to be 4 variables? Can you save them in an array? This is a perfect use of a recursive method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them in an array, loop through them, and use them as the keys in an object to see if they're unique.

```
var obj = {};
var arr = [a, b, c, d];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] in obj) {
        console.log("Duplicate of " + arr[i] + " found");
        break;
    }
    obj[arr[i]] = true;
}
```

Also, if you're using libraries like jQuery or Underscore.js, they have functions for getting the unique elements of an array, you can use that.

```
if ($.unique([a, b, c, d]).length == 4) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that was the tip - placing them in an array :-)

Comment: Whenever you have a collection of things that you want to treat in some uniform way, your first inclination should be to put them in an array. Programming 101.

Comment: @usermod2 I would take a look at my answer. Modern and vanilla JavaScript has a better solution to handle unique collections!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for checking that all values are unique, since ECMA-Script 6 and above, you can use `Set` collection (a set is an unordered collection of unique values):

```js
var a = 'aword';
var b = 'bword';
var c = 'cword';
var d = 'dword';
var values = [a, b, c, d];
var set = new Set(values);

if (set.size == values.length) {
  alert("they're all distinct values");
}
```

`Set` is already available in modern versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE11, Safari ([see brower compatibility on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)).

Comment: This looks good - however concerned about full browser support

Comment: @userMod2 That's why I've given you a link to check browser support. AFAIK, if you're just looking for solving this specific problem, since you're using `Set` in a very limited way, it seems very safe. Anyway, you could use a polyfill like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-set